# How to find SPO sites that have 3rd party apps installed

Tags: app

We have some people who have installed apps from the sharepoint App Store. (Adobe Sign)

How can i get a list of all sites within our o365 tenant that have this (or other 3rd party apps) installed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command :

```
Get-SPOAppInfo -Name " " | Sort Name
```

**Description about the Get-SPOAppInfo command:**

The Get-SPOAppInfo cmdlet gets all the installed applications from an external marketplace or from the App Catalog that contain Name in their application names or the installed application with mentioned ProductId. ProductId takes precedence if not empty.

MSDN Reference:

[Get-SPOAppInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spoappinfo?view=sharepoint-ps)

We can use the below PnP code:

```
Get-PnPApp
```

The above command will return all apps installed in the "App Catalog" site collection(tenant-level). We can write for each loop something like below to get the details about the specific app.

```
$allAppsInAppCatalog=Get-PnPApp

foreach($oneApp in $allAppsInAppCatalog)
{
  #Now. using the $oneApp attribute we can get the details of a particular app.    
  Write-Host $oneApp.Title
}
```

For detailed about the  Get-PnPApp command refer to the below MSDN article:

[Get-PnPApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Using the client-side CSOM C# code**

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://youroffice-admin.sharepoint.com")) 
{ 
    
    Tenant tenant = new Tenant(context);
    tenant.Context.Load(tenant);
    tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();


    var appCatalogAppInfoCollection = tenant.GetAppInfoByName(string.Empty);
    tenant.Context.Load(appCatalogAppInfoCollection);
    tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

    foreach (var app in appCatalogAppInfoCollection)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("APP: " + app.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine("Source: " + app.Source);
    }
}
```

Source:

[How to get the list of custom apps in App catalog using Powershell?](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-get-the-list-of-custom-apps-in-app-catalog-using-powershell/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quickl reply. Get-PNPApp seems to only apps deployed in the catalog. It does not show apps installed from the Microsoft store.

Comment: Ohhk - you can use this command Get-SPOAppInfo   - the MSDN description says the Get-SPOAppInfo cmdlet gets all the installed applications from an external marketplace or from the App Catalog that contains Name in their application names or the installed application with mentioned ProductId.  please see the updated answer.

Comment: yeah, that shows all apps installed on the tenant., but not what sites their on , I finally found rest api https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/apptiles.  Each AppTile returned has an AppSource. I believe appsource of 1 means its from the store. Still testing.

Comment: Good, you have found another alternate solution REST API... however, I think using the command Get-SPOAppInfo  , we can get app information... try to loop through this collection then inside foreach loop we can each individual app details.... I have not tested this, but generally it is supposed to be. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Get-SPOAppInfo does work when i call it on each individual  site.

Comment: Oh great, nice to hear Get-SPOAppInfo works... if this helps you could you mark this as answered, so that it will help to the upcoming visitors :-)

Comment: Does this solution list the sites that have a specific app installed? I thin that was the original question....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this & I found this article:  https://olafd.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/show-all-installed-apps-for-a-sharepoint-site/ helped me the most.

I started off running this against a few sites I knew had apps installed. I started by removing the condition block *if ($appType -eq "Instance")* - but I found that all the apps I was looking for were AppType : Instance, so I ended up adding it back in later

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
#Note: PnP Powershell v2.1.1 does not work with Powershell v5. Downgrade to 1.12.0 to use in PowerShell v5 (including ISE)
#Install-Module PnP.Powershell -RequiredVersion 1.12.0
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<domain>-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $Cred
$Url = "https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $Url –Credentials $Cred
$web = Get-PnPWeb –Includes AppTiles
$appTiles = $web.AppTiles
Invoke-PNPQuery
foreach ($appTile in $appTiles)
{
    Write-Host -f Green "Site:" $SiteUrl                  
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Title =" $appTile.Title
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppType =" $appTile.AppType
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppStatus =" $appTile.AppStatus
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppSource =" $appTile.AppSource
    Write-Host -f Magenta "IsCorporateCatalogSite =" $appTile.IsCorporateCatalogSite
}
```

My final script to iterate across all sites is something like this:

----Note: replace the text *yourdomain* with the domain for your organization

```
#variables
$Cred = Get-Credential
$AdminURL = "https://yourdomain-admin.sharepoint.com/"  
$siteURLs = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/*"
$UserName = $Cred.UserName
$Password = $Cred.Password
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $Password

#Note: PnP.Powershell v2.1.1 does not work with Powershell v5. Downgrade to 1.12.0 to use PnP.Powershell in PowerShell v5 (including Powershell ISE)
#Remove-Module PnP.PowerShell -force
#Install-Module PnP.Powershell -RequiredVersion 1.12.0

    Try{
        #Import and connect to Sharepoint Online
        Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
        Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminURL -Credential $Cred

        #Get ALL Sharepoint sites
        $Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

        #This script will jump down to the section labeled "Search all sites for 'real' sharepoint sites - not OneDrive etc"
        #This is because everything inbetween is a Function, and those Functions have not been called yet

        #Function to connect to the Sharepoint site
        Function ConnectToSPSite() {
            try {
                #Connecting to Sharepoint admin     
                Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminURL -Credentials $Credentials              
                try{
                    #Connecting to the Sharepoint site
                    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credentials                                                      
                } catch {
                            Write-Host "ERROR: Failed to connect to $($SiteUrl). Verify the user running this script has ownership rights on the site." -f Red
                            Continue
                    }
                
                #Call the Function GetAPPListItems to get installed Sharepoint applications.
                GetAPPItems                
            } catch {                
                Write-Host "ERROR: could not connect to Site:'$($SiteUrl)'" $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
                Continue               
            } 
        }

        #Function to get all apps from site
        Function GetAPPItems() {       
            Try{
                #Setup the connection to the Sharepoint site
                $SiteConn = ""
                $SiteConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credentials -ReturnConnection               
                $error.clear()

                #Get the site information including the site Apps
                try{
                    $web = Get-PnPWeb –Includes AppTiles
                    $appTiles = $web.AppTiles
                    Invoke-PnPQuery

                    #Review all apps
                    foreach ($appTile in $appTiles)
                    {   
                        #Filter out to show only the Apps that are the AppType: "Instance"
                        If($appTile.AppType -eq "Instance"){

                            #Write out this information for the user running the script
                            Write-Host -f Green "Site:" $SiteUrl                  
                            Write-Host -f Yellow "Title =" $appTile.Title
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppType =" $appTile.AppType
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppStatus =" $appTile.AppStatus
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppSource =" $appTile.AppSource
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "IsCorporateCatalogSite =" $appTile.IsCorporateCatalogSite
                        }
                    } 
                }catch{
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error running Get-PnPWeb on site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error:" $errormsg
                    Continue
                }
            }catch{
                    Write-Host -f Red "Unable to connect to PnP site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error:" $errormsg
                    Write-Log "Unable to connect to PnP site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Log "Error:" $errormsg
                    Continue
            }
        }

        #Search all sites for 'real' Sharepoint sites - not OneDrive etc
        foreach($site in $sites)
            {
                #Empty variables that change often
                $SiteURL = ""
                $SiteConn = ""
                #Check the site URL to see if it is a 'real' SharePoint site. Omit empty sites.
                $SiteURL = $site.URL
                If ($site.URL -like $siteURLs -and $site.StorageQuota -ne 0)           
                    {                                        
                        #Call the Function ConnectToSPSite to begin by connecting to the SharePoint site
                        ConnectToSPSite             
                    }  
            }
    
    } Catch {
        Write-Host "ERROR: $errormsg"
    }
```